# How can I fill combo box with data returned by Stored Procedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, combobox, dapper

I want fill the combo box with data from SQL stored procedure. I have no idea how can i get data from procedure and fill combo box with it.

There is my code from C#:

```
private void CategoryCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connection = Connection.ConnectionFactory.GetOpenConnection())
        {
            DynamicParameters par = new DynamicParameters();
            string category = categoryCombo.SelectedValue.ToString();
            int cid = Int32.Parse(category);
            par.Add("@Category", cid);
            connection.Execute("Get_lineFromSchema", par, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        }
    }
```

Following is the Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Get_lineFromSchema](@Category int) as
select bs.Line_id, l.name from Budget_Scheme bs
inner join B_Line l on l.Line_id=bs.Line_id
where bs.Budget_id=1 and bs.Category_id = @Category
group by bs.Line_id, l.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("Get_lineFromSchema", conn);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", cid);

            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
            DataTable result = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(result);

            CategoryCombo.DataSource = result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using this and its works, thanks for help:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAP100MK\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=HomeBudgetAPP;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
            string category = categoryCombo.SelectedValue.ToString();
            int cid = Int32.Parse(category);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Get_lines", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", cid);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable result = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(result);
            LineCombo.DataSource = result;
            LineCombo.DisplayMember = "Name";
            LineCombo.ValueMember = "Line_id";
            }
```